# Changing the position of items

Tags: android, layout

My xml file lists items in left, what I want to change thier positions to right.I've tried `android:layout_gravity="right"`, but it didn't work!, I have also item.xml and list_item.xml.The following code is list.xml

```
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/edit_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >       
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/list_descption_label"
                android:gravity="left"
            />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/list_username_label"
                android:gravity="left"
            />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/list_password_label"
                android:gravity="left"
            />
                        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/edit_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingTop="5sp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="hello" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="hai" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="nams" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>



<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If it is list_item then i think ScrollView is not needed.

Comment: Ya. If it is list, no need of scroll view.